Control an element in the layout based on the item loaded in the main page
I have a page, which is populated based on the application selected in the layout.
app1 >> menu items1 >> page1
this works fine. However, if i access the main page through URL, the app doesn't reflect the selection.
what shows is,
page 2 << menu item1 << app1
instead of
page 2 << menu item2 << app2
this is problem.
if i try to change the app dropdown, based on the link then it triggers onchange event, which refreshes everything.
if I get to the main page through this route then no issues,
app1 - menu 1 - menu 1 page
if i access the menu page directly then it does not work - when i try to access menu 2 page
app1 - menu1 - menu 2 page
instead of app2 - menu 2 - menu 2 page. in this case if i use the url to report 2 then the app that contains the project 2 should be selected in the dropdown (layout) and the menu items should be based on the app 2. - this is not happening. Trying to change the selected value in JS triggers on change.

How do i resolve this?

Trying to understand the URL

The URL when i access the menu item is - https://localhost:44343/Home/LoadMenu2Page

The URL when i access the project page is - https://localhost:44343/Home/LoadProject2Page

I understand why this happens, which is, i am accessing an action. I keep thinking why it is not like, https://localhost:44343/Home/LoadMenu2Page/LoadProject2Page?



in the real case, the link is,
https://localhost:44343/portal/allprojects
https://localhost:44343/portal/GetProjectDetails?projecid=1
I need to be able to include appid too, i am confused about how to implement this?
Would it look like, https://localhost:44343/portal/GetProjectDetails?projecid=1  or https://localhost:44343/portal/GetProjectDetails?projecid=1


I know that I have not articulated the situation properly but i keep getting confused when i think through this. Can someone please tell me how this has to be structured and where am i thinking wrong?
_Layout.cshtml
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SampleLocal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/SampleLocal.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>


<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-warning justify-content-between" style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <span> Application: </span>
                    <select>
                        <option>app1</option>
                        <option>app2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <span> Application name </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    role: user role ||
                    <span>user name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 ms-4 border-end">
            <partial name="~/views/shared/_MenuItemsPartial.cshtml" /> @* partial view to load menu items *@
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 align-self-center border-start">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

Shared > _MenuItemsPartial.cshtml
@* list of menu items for a project *@
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified flex-column" id="menu">
    <li class="active">
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" > 
            menu 1 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadMenu2Page" > 
            menu 2  
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadMenu3Page" > 
             menu 3 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

Home > Index
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Projects List - menu 1 </h2></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Project number</th>
      <th scope="col">Project name</th>
      <th scope="col">Stakeholder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadProject1Page">1</a></th>
      <td>user login</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadProject2Page">2</a></th>
      <td>log hours</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoadProject3Page">3</a></th>
      <td>feeback portal</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Home > Menu2PartialView.cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Projects List - Menu 2 </h2></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Project number</th>
      <th scope="col">Project name</th>
      <th scope="col">Stakeholder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject1Page">1</a></th>
      <td>user login</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject2Page">2</a></th>
      <td>log hours</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject3Page">3</a></th>
      <td>feeback portal</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Home > Menu3PartialView.cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Projects List - Menu 3</h2></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Project number</th>
      <th scope="col">Project name</th>
      <th scope="col">Stakeholder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject1Page">1</a></th>
      <td>user login</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject2Page">2</a></th>
      <td>log hours</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="/Home/LoadProject3Page">3</a></th>
      <td>feeback portal</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Home > Project1PartialView.cshtml
<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Project details - Project 1 </h2></div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"> <b> <- Go back</b></button>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

Home > Project2PratialView.cshtml
<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Project details - Project 2</h2></div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"> <b> <- Go back</b></button>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

Home > Project3PartialView.cshtml
<div class="m-3 text-center fw-bold"><h2> Project details - Project 3 </h2></div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"> <b> <- Go back</b></button>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

Controllers > HomeController
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //public IActionResult LoadMenu1Page()
    //{
    //    return View("~/Views/Home/Menu1PartialView.cshtml");
    //}
    public IActionResult LoadMenu2Page()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Menu2PartialView.cshtml");
    }
    public IActionResult LoadMenu3Page()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Menu3PartialView.cshtml");
    }

    public IActionResult LoadProject1Page()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Project1PartialView.cshtml");
    }
    public IActionResult LoadProject2Page()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Project2PartialView.cshtml");
    }
    public IActionResult LoadProject3Page()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Project3PartialView.cshtml");
    }


    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}

Since these were partial views, i split them into views for the menu item page.

You need to use asp-route-yourParameter attributes in your links.  See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-9.0#asp-route-value  You'd then read/bind the parameters to provide the response.  Not real sure those partials are helping you here.  Maybe just use separate controllers/views.
